# best CMS for a custom and new employees?

Tags: php, wordpress, drupal, content-management-system, joomla

we're moving to use an OPENSOURCE CMS system, for years we been using our own CMS, and it's time to move to OPENSOURCE. so which of Drupal, Joomla, WordPress is the best choice if

1. the team needs to learn it ...
2. supporting multi languages and RTL directions
3. easy to use ( for end users )
4. customization and templating

or if there are any other CMS that would make the process faster.

thanks all

Comment: Wordpress is honestly the most user friendly, and developer friendly I've seen from a UI perspective. But from a code perspective, I would stay away from it. After learning and understanding the Magento framework (and more importantly MVC) it just seems so sloppy. May I ask why you are converting from a custom CMS?

Comment: [belongs on serverfault?] [btw where did that reason go for closing?]

Comment: @Dalton WordPress is amazing, am impressed by what it can offer but i think it lacks in customization. i been working on a custom CMS for almost 2 years and implement for more than 50 website, but now our team is extended, and we need a stander way to work. and the time is important. any add that could have with few clicks in Drupal for example would have a day or two to implement for custom CMS

Comment: @Jason i don't understand you

Answer (score 6):

If you want to develop a robust application in a relatively quick fashion you should give Drupal a try. It's fantastic for intranet like systems. A lot of the more popular modules are very abstract and allow you to craft custom content to display in very custom ways easily.

I prefer it over WP and specially over Joomla!.

Comment: thanks, Joomla is the worst i used it before and i disliked it. i think Drupal is the winning one here

Comment: Joomla!'s interface is confusing also whereas Drupals structure actually depends so much on how I myself create the elements that goes inside it. Joomla has taken my time for long enough, I am better using it because I now value how well Drupal is put together.

Answer (score 4):

I've used all 3, and they all have different advantages. It would help to know what exactly you're doing, but here are some vague generalities:

Wordpress is very focused on the task of blogging, so visual design and usability tend to be much better. Joomla has more resale-friendly licensing, so there's more money to be made in that business model. Drupal is more of a generic framework, so good for heavy customization.

1. Ease of learning really depends on what you're doing with it. Drupal is more complex to learn, but can do a lot. Wordpress is easiest, but is still very focused on blogs. So if you're primarily doing blogs, go with Wordpress. If you're doing more, consider Drupal.
2. They all support multiple languages and RTL, so that's not a big difference.
3. This is pretty much the same as #1. Wordpress wins at what it does, but if that's not what you're doing, it's irrelevant.

4a. I think Drupal wins hands-down for customization. Drupal's the only system that allows you to heavily alter what others have created without managing their codebase. For example, Drupal creates all forms as arrays and exposes them to any code to modify after they're created. Both Wordpress and Joomla create forms as straight HTML, so you can only alter it by altering the code that creates it, which quickly turns into a maintenance headache.

4b. I think Wordpress wins for templating. It has a clean division between code and design, which Drupal lacks, and some established standards for markup, which Joomla lacks.

As you can see, Joomla doesn't win at all here, so I wouldn't suggest it. I'm guessing your needs are more complex than what Wordpress does well, but that's just a guess. Based on that guess, I'd suggest Drupal.

Comment: Amazing, i think you give me what i want. because i know Drupal is amazing. actually i like WordPress designing and templating and on other-hand i like Drupal power. but drupal can be customize too to have a rock  template. so am going to use drupal

Answer (score 1):

ExpressionEngine

It supports multiple languages.

Templating is a cinch.

It is not OpenSource, but is that a requirement, or just a preference?

Check out an earlier response I made about a question that relates to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250880/is-there-any-cms-better-than-wordpress-or-should-i-roll-my-own/251392#251392

I have heard good things about SilverStripe (never used it), that is a opensource php cms http://silverstripe.org/

Comment: thanks, i like not opensource prodocts, but i think Drupal is better because everybody helping and contributing the project

Answer (score 1):

I give my vote to Joomla!  Joomla! has one of the most active support forums.  Ask a question it will be answered over 90% of the time.  There are numerous professional template sites that charge very little for single template usage.

Joomla! grows bigger and bigger by the day.  Just go to [www.joomla.org](http://www.joomla.org) and see for yourself.

Good luck.

Comment: Joomla- spaghetti code, pay-for modules, little support.

Comment: I agree with @Kevin personally I prefer Drupal.

Comment: thanks, i used Joomla before and really i don't like it. it was a bad experience with Joomla specially how APIis and how people are working to extend it